# So, what happened on the site that we all suddenly got "Generalist" badges?

Tags: discussion, tags, badges

Idle question: "Generalist" was one of the badges that nobody had, and now suddenly a whole bunch of us were awarded it. Was there some hidden time-related condition on it that the site met? Or did someone merge a bunch of tags?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The engine only starts awarding Generalist badges once the top 40 tags have at least 200 questions each. Reg tagged and re-tagged a lot of stuff this morning.  Thanks, Reg.

Comment: More like the last two weeks. And still work in progress. In fact, in two tags we've fallen below the threshold again (some old stuff got deleted).

Comment: Ah! The "minimum number of questions" part is what I was wondering. Thanks, Kit & Reg!

Comment: @RegDwighт It does appear that gaining badges works both ways. I still have the Notification "You've gained the **Meaning** badge" but it no longer appears in my profile. `:-(`

Comment: @Andrew: Tag badges, as opposed to other badges, can be revoked — for no other reason that tags themselves can go the way of the dodo. However, since the "meaning" tag is still around, soon enough you'll qualify for that badge *again* and will get it back.

Answer (score 0):

Also see the [data.stackexchange query](http://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/11020/is-the-site-ready-for-the-generalist-badge)  “Is the site ready for the Generalist Badge?”.  It shows question counts for the top 40 tags on a site.  The database the numbers are drawn from is updated monthly.  The last few lines of the already-obsolete present view are shown below.

```
Tagname        Uses   Questions Needed with this Tag...

adverbs        269    -69
history        232    -32
tense          222    -22
word-order     210    -10
articles       190    10
writing        174    26
capitalization 169    31
possessive     159    41
antonyms       157    43
abbreviations  157    43
conjunctions   153    47
sentence       148    52
```